# How to make IME(Input Method Editor) simulator by python?

Tags: python, ime, automata

```
def IME(self) : #it is total function
    output = ""
    print "Exit by ctrl + D"
    while 1 :
        character = raw_input("")
        if character in self.alphabet :
            result = self.transition(character) # get result [next state, output character] from constructed by automata
            output = output + str(result[1])
            print output
            self.currentState = result[0]
        else :
            output = output + character
            print output


    self.currentState = 0
```

I make a IME(Input Method Editor) simulator by python. It is like finite state machine, when input come and output shows result on python program. I don't know the result show one by one, so I want to ask you how to show just like command line style.

The Question is two things,

1. How to express each result one by one?
2. How to implement "space" or "backspace"?
3. Is it okay using this code when 'del(backspace) key' input?

   ```
       elif character == '\033'
           output = output[0:len(output)-1]
   ```

Comment: Would you mind providing the code to the rest of your class?

Comment: Check out the [`code`](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html#module-code) module.